# Downloaded font doesn't work in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, internet-explorer-11, truetype

I downloaded a font but i can't get it to work in Google Chrome, yet in IE11 it is visible.

CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'caviardreams';
src: url('../Lettertypen/caviardreams-webfont.eot');
src: url('../Lettertypen/caviardreams-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../Lettertypen/caviardreams-webfont.woff">../Lettertypen/caviardreams-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../Lettertypen/caviardreams-webfont.ttf">../Lettertypen/caviardreams-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
     url('../Lettertypen/caviardreams-webfont.svg">../Lettertypen/caviardreams-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
```

}

I know that Chrome supports ttf and svg so that should be covered but it still doesn't work... Help anyone? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you looked in Chrome's console for errors?

Comment: Thanks, figgered out what went wrong!

Comment: Why not answer your own question then.

Comment: Of course! I pasted the same thing twice in a row for the ttf file and the svg file. Silly, immediately saw it when I used chrome's console to look for errors.